# Codeigniter - cookies do not work in internet explorer 8

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, internet-explorer-8

This code works in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8

```
 $this->input->set_cookie(array(
                          'name'   => 'test_cookie',
                          'value'  => 'hello from cookie',
                          'expire' => 360000000,
                          'secure' => FALSE
                          ));

        echo get_cookie('test_cookie');
```

How to solve this problem? Why does not set_cookie?

Comment: The cookies aren't being set? What if you set them without using codeigniter?

Comment: can you confirm your code works on FF, CHrome etc ??

Comment: This code works in all browsers!

Comment: @AlmasSarsenbayev do you have cookies enabled on browser IE ?

Comment: Cookies are enabled IE, other sites use cookies work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
echo $this->input->cookie('test_cookie');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where only IE would refuse to accept a cookie. Turned out the computer's time zone wasn't set correctly (it was 17 hours ahead in the future, set to US PST while the server was in Australia), so what was happening is that the cookie was instantly expiring.

Comment: Thanks I just had this exact same problem - while using the Microsoft supplied dev virtual machine for IE11. The clock had the "right" time on it but was set to US PST so it was effectively in the past. Very difficult to diagnose as the cookie was just being ignored! I'd tried many things, but your answer made me check the clock in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the function in helper

```
function setcookie_ex($name, $value, $expire)
{
    $cookie_path = '/'; $cookie_domain = ''; $cookie_secure = false;

    // Enable sending of a P3P header
    header('P3P: CP="CUR ADM"');

    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.0', '>='))
       setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $cookie_secure, true);
    else
    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $cookie_path.'; HttpOnly', $cookie_domain, $cookie_secure);
}
```