# cookie did not send back to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

In my codeigniter app I set a cookie named "token" which is a JWT token. I can see it working when I see this in Chrome console. but when I do further request, eg. browse another pages I don't see the "token" send back to the server, the `Cookie` header only send `ci_session` cookie.

here is the cookie send by the server.

[image]

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743871/why-doesnt-cookie-work-in-codeigniter

Comment: thanks. but nevermind, it's my mistake i didn't check the cookie expiration(it's already expired when server send it to client).