# set_cookie not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am try to set cookie for idle lock concept; if idle for 5 minutes then CI will redirect to locked screen - have I have already tried set_cookie also, but still not able to store cookie

```
**autoload.php**
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','cookie'); 



**config.php**
    $config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
    $config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
    $config['cookie_path']      = '/';
    $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
    $config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
    -------------------------------
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 300;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 60;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
-------------------------------

**user -> login method**
$this->input->set_cookie('uid','5', time()+86400,'/');
$this->input->set_cookie('type','sa', time()+86400,'/');
-------------------------------

**dashboard-> index method**
 <?php print_r($this->input->cookie()); ?>
```

Comment: `print_r($this->input->cookie('uid'));` try like this

Comment: already tried not working @MayankVadiya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't cookie work in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743871/why-doesnt-cookie-work-in-codeigniter)